# very Strange problem with text area value and javascript

Tags: php, javascript, html

i have a html form

```
<form action="" method="post">
<textarea id="content" name="content"></textarea >
</form>
```

ok it work good when making `var_dump($_post);`
but the problem is when adding any js plugin on this textarea its not give me any out put
this in my new script i cant know the reason
i testes many plugins
like text area resize like nic editor like ckeditor
and many things
every thing is ok and i can not know the reason
the problem is every thing is ok and there is a problem
its give me empty if i write any thing in the textarea

Comment: Can you provide the example with the js plugin enabled?

Comment: on PHP's documentation http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php I don't see use of $_post only $_POST (uppercase)... is that the issue (I'm presuming PHP is case-sensitive here)

Comment: @scunliffe i know that and i write it like that $_POST too

Comment: The problem is related to this mysterious JS plugin you've said so much about...

Comment: That is one enormous sentence!

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume you are using [Yui's RTE](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/editor/) because I had this issue with it.

Because of the way that Yui RTE works, you need to call `saveHTML()` to ensure that any text typed is actually re-assigned to the textarea value.

[Read the Docs](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/editor/#getdata)